# my tic-tac-toe program in matlab does not work

Tags: matlab

I have written a tic-tac-toe game in matlab but it does not work:

```
%// 1) Commence the game, display empty board 

board=cell(3);

%// 2) Select which player is ?X? and ?O? (at random) 

playersymbols={'X','O'};
playersymbolindex=randperm(2);
for i=1:2
    player(i).symbol=playersymbols{playersymbolindex(i)};
end

winner=0;

while winner<1 
    %// 3) Request player1?s move

    player1move=input('Player 1, please enter your move: ');

    %// the input is something like [1 3] where the first number is the
    %// row number and the second number is column number so that [1 3] will
    %// put X in row 1, column 3.

    %// Redraw updated board. 
    board{player1move(1),player1move(2)}=player(1).symbol;
    board



    %// 5) Decision: has the game been won yet? If so, go to step 9).
    %//    If not, go to step 6). 

    %// The game is won when three respective X are placed in a horizontal,
    %// vertical, or diagonal row.

    if board{1,1}==board{1,2} & board {1,2}==board{1,3} | ...
       board{2,1}==board{2,2} & board{2,2}==board{2,3} | ...
       board{3,1}==board{3,2} & board{3,2}==board{3,3} | ...
       board{1,1}==board{2,1} & board{2,1}==board{3,1} | ...
       board{1,2}==board{2,2} & board{2,2}==board{3,2} | ...
       board{1,3}==board{2,3} & board{2,3}==board{3,3} | ...
       board{1,1}==board{2,2} & board{2,2}==board{3,3} | ...
       board{1,3}==board{2,2} & board{2,2}==board{3,1}

        %// 9) Display winner on the screen. 

        disp('Winner is player 1!')

        winner=1; 
    else

        %// 6) Request player2?s move 

        player2move=input('Player 2, please enter your move: ');

        %// 7) Input Player2?s move. Redraw updated board.

        board{player2move(1),player2move(2)}=player(2).symbol;
        board


        %// 8) Decision: has the game been won yet? If so, go to step 9). 
        %//    If not, go back to step 3). 

        if board{1,1}==board{1,2} & board {1,2}==board{1,3} | ...
           board{2,1}==board{2,2} & board{2,2}==board{2,3} | ...
           board{3,1}==board{3,2} & board{3,2}==board{3,3} | ...
           board{1,1}==board{2,1} & board{2,1}==board{3,1} | ...
           board{1,2}==board{2,2} & board{2,2}==board{3,2} | ...
           board{1,3}==board{2,3} & board{2,3}==board{3,3} | ...
           board{1,1}==board{2,2} & board{2,2}==board{3,3} | ...
           board{1,3}==board{2,2} & board{2,2}==board{3,1}

           %// 9) Display winner on the screen. 

           disp('Winner is player 2!')
           winner=1;
        end
    end
end
```

I tried very hard to understand what I am doing wrong but after 4 hours, I am clueless what I am doing wrong. Could someone please help me? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** Player 1 is ok so the issue is with Player 2. When Player 2 wins, my program does not display that "player 2 has won the game" and wrongly asks for player 1 next move (while the game was already finished).

Comment: You have to be explicit about what is not working. Describe exactly what doesn't work and what you've done to try and debug it

Comment: @Dan: I just edited my question. If the edit at the end of my question is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: I am new to MatLab so I do not know how to debug it.

Comment: I dont know, it worked for me. Can you post specific inputs? I tried player 1 allways `[1 1]` and player 2 the second column. It worked.

Comment: It works fine for me as well, my player 2 inputs were `[2,2]`, `[2,1]` and `[2,3]` and it displayed that player 2 won and exited the loop

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Thanks for your help. This is my inputs: `[1 1]`, `[1 2]`, `[2 1]`, `[2 2]`, `[1 3]`, `[3 2]`. I am using Matlab on Mac. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Dan: Does my inputs work for you?

Comment: @mathema no they don't - I get the same incorrect behaviour as you...

Comment: By the way, is there a better way to program this. I think my programming is really amateur?

Comment: @Dan: That is why I do not understand what the problem is. It works for some and not for others.

Comment: @mathema I think you just need brackets around each line of your if statement before the `|`... but also you should use short circuit operations like `&&` and `||`

Comment: @mathema There is indeed way better ways of programming this, and taking constrains also into accound. If you want help on that, go to codereview.stackexchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Steffen and I would also make the comparison a separate function. Here is an implementation:

```
%// 1) Commence the game, display empty board 

board=cell(3);

%// 2) Select which player is ?X? and ?O? (at random) 

playersymbols={'X','O'};
playersymbolindex=randperm(2);
for i=1:2
    player(i).symbol=playersymbols{playersymbolindex(i)};
end

winner=0;

while winner<1 
    %// 3) Request player1?s move

    player1move=input('Player 1, please enter your move: ');

    %// the input is something like [1 3] where the first number is the
    %// row number and the second number is column number so that [1 3] will
    %// put X in row 1, column 3.

    %// Redraw updated board. 
    board{player1move(1),player1move(2)}=player(1).symbol;
    board



    %// 5) Decision: has the game been won yet? If so, go to step 9).
    %//    If not, go to step 6). 

    %// The game is won when three respective X are placed in a horizontal,
    %// vertical, or diagonal row.

    if gameWon(board, player(1).symbol)

        %// 9) Display winner on the screen. 

        disp('Winner is player 1!')

        winner=1; 
    else

        %// 6) Request player2?s move 

        player2move=input('Player 2, please enter your move: ');

        %// 7) Input Player2?s move. Redraw updated board.

        board{player2move(1),player2move(2)}=player(2).symbol;
        board


        %// 8) Decision: has the game been won yet? If so, go to step 9). 
        %//    If not, go back to step 3). 

        if gameWon(board, player(2).symbol)

           %// 9) Display winner on the screen. 

           disp('Winner is player 2!')
           winner=1;
        end
    end
end
```

And the function `gameWon`:

```
function result = gameWon(board, playersymbol)
    result = (isequal(board{1,1},board{1,2},playersymbol) && isequal(board{1,1},board{1,3},playersymbol)) || ...
             %// repeat for all your cases
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I spotted the problem.

As you are comparing Strings with the `==` and not with `strcmp`, when there are empty strings the comparison returns `[]`. Therefore a logical operator of `TRUE | []` returns `[]` which is not true.

In the example you posted ([1 1], [1 2], [2 1], [2 2], [1 3], [3 2]) the last line of the `if` returns `[]`

```
board{1,3}==board{2,2} & board{2,2}==board{3,1}
```

It looks like if you substitute your logical operators by `&&` and `||` you can fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is real strage behaviour.

your if clause does work if your first statement is 1.

You should initialize your board with some default value liek '-'.
And then use the operators && and || instead of & and |.
You then also need t check for the correct symbol of the actual player.

Answer (score 0):

& and | are element-wise logical comparisons, if you use them on a cell whose content is empty, the result is a 0x0 matrix.

Then you compare the resulting 0x0 matrix to other stuff, which might also be 0x0 matrizes or logical TRUE or logical FALSE. In any case the program does not do what you think it does within the if condition.

Easiest way to fix this is by subsituting | by || and & by &&, because the latter two always return logical FALSE or TRUE as a result.