# order of values in logical expression in if-clause

Tags: matlab

```
if 1 | []
    disp('1 | []');
end

if [] | 1
    disp('[] | 1');
end
```

results in `1 | []`. The first if is executed.

How come this behaviour?
I would assume both have the same result.

Comment: Do a quick search on Yoda Conditions, you may find some of the behavioural differences on the wiki page :-)

Comment: Interesting, since on the command line, both conditions evaluate to `[]`

Comment: I was going to ask the same question, but you are faster!

Comment: Origin of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30047471/my-tic-tac-toe-program-in-matlab-does-not-work?noredirect=1#comment48212276_30047471

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that this is most likely a interpreter-induced bug, although MathWorks might claim it's undefined behavior.

On the command line, both `cond1 = 1|[];` and `cond2 = []|1;` evaluate to `[]`, because all operations involving `[]` return `[]`. Since `[]` evaluates to `false` if used in a condition, one would therefore expect both cases to behave the same way if used in an if-clause.

Aside from the array-wise logical operators, Matlab also offers short-circuit operators, where the evaluation of conditions is stopped if the result is clear from looking at parts of the condition only. Evaluated on the command line, the array-wise operation `1|[]` returns `[]`, while the short-circuit operation `1||[]` returns `1`. Note that `[]||1` throws an error, since the short-circuit operator only works with scalar conditions, unless it never has to evaluate them.

So far, everything is as expected. What I suspect happens in our unexpected case is that the interpreter implicitly replaces `1|[]` by `1||[]` inside the if-clause, possibly because the operation starts with a scalar, and `[]` is not an array.

If at all possible, you should avoid calculating with `[]`, and catch potential such cases with `isempty`.

Comment: The fun thing is that is not interpreted as false *until the end*. Which means that  ` ([ ] | 1)| 1` is false.

Answer (score 1):

As Matlab interprets logical operations in if statements only when the result does depend on it. Interpreting `1 | X` is usually true no matter what the second expression is, so the interpreter will take the shortcut (wrongly in case `X = []`.
`[] | X` is false no matter what the second expression is, so the result is false.

Comment: But the result of `[]|x` is not false, is `[]`. Then the if statement intepretes it as "not true"

Comment: This is actually called short-circuit: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logicaloperatorsshortcircuit.html

Comment: Good point; I suspect Matlab erroneously short-circuits in this case (Note: Matlab has explicit short-circuit operators)